# Are there ways of doing opendir(), readdir() type of calls through SSH/SFTP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, openssh, dirent.h

I have a bit of code that reads a directory for files to process. I currently use the dirent.h,opendir(),readdir() methods of doing this. I have been told that I need to do the same thing, only now it is a directory on a remote machine with SSH/SFTP access.

The only way (that I can think of) to do the same thing, without changing anything in the system except my source code, is to run a "ssh user@host ls" command, parse, and process based on the parsers results.

The real question here is, are there ways of doing opendir(), readdir() (or something similar) through SSH/SFTP?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, if you're on Linux or Mac OS X (or some BSDs) would be to use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to attach it to the filesystem. Most filesystem calls will then just work directly without modification.

Otherwise you can look at sshfs's [source](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc#kBdOMN5obeE/sshfs-fuse-1.6/sshfs.c&q=sshfs&l=140) for hints about how it does things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SFTP has a protocol for doing this. Read through the most recent document here: http://tools.ietf.org/wg/secsh/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer/

Comment: Is this implemented anywhere?

Comment: It concerns me that OpenSSH doesn't seem to have a stable API or any API documentation except in-code remarks.

Comment: sshfs just runs ssh as a separate process and speaks raw SFTP over a pipe, obviating the need for a stable API

Comment: OpenSSH implements a network protocol, not an API - there is no standard SSH API. sshfs is one alternative, otherwise you need to use an SFTP client library.

Answer (score 0):

As of OpenSSH 5.1, there is a limited implementation to do this. It does not fully implement the File XFER standard. So I cannot check for things like the file types, but I can scan for the filenames themselves... Using the "sftp.c" code in OpenSSH source I just threw together an adhoc main() that could be changed as needed... I hope that this question can be more thoughly answered at a later date.

```
/* Username is a NULL terminated string
   Host is a NULL terminated string indicating remote IP */
void setup_args(arglist *args, char *username, char *host)
{
        // Arg init allocation
        memset(args, '\0', sizeof(*args));
        args->list = NULL;

        // Arg setup
        addargs(args, "%s", "/usr/bin/ssh");
        addargs(args, "%s", "-oForwardX11 no");
        addargs(args, "%s", "-oForwardAgent no");
        addargs(args, "%s", "-oPermitLocalCommand no");
        addargs(args, "%s", "-oClearAllForwardings yes");
        addargs(args, "%s%s", "-l", username);
        addargs(args, "%s", "-oProtocol 2");
        addargs(args, "%s", "-s");
        addargs(args, "%s", host);
        addargs(args, "%s", "sftp");
}
void run_program()
{
        // Setup connection parameters.
        int in, out; // The IO file descriptors.
        arglist args;
        setup_args(&args, "chenz", "172.16.22.128");
        connect_to_server("/usr/bin/ssh", args.list, &in, &out);
        freeargs(&args);

        // Create connection
        struct sftp_conn *conn;
        conn = do_init(in, out, copy_buffer_len, num_requests);
        if (conn == NULL)
                fatal("Couldn't initialise connection to server");

        //Get the current directory
        char *pwd;
        pwd = do_realpath(conn, ".");
        printf("PWD: %s\n", pwd);
        if (pwd == NULL)
                fatal("Need cwd");

        SFTP_DIRENT** dirent;
        do_readdir(conn, "/home/chenz", &dirent);
        int i = 0;
        while (dirent[i] != 0) {
                printf("filename: %s\n", dirent[i]->filename);
                printf("longname: %s\n", dirent[i]->longname);
                printf("attrib:\n", dirent[i]->a);
                i++;
        }

        // Clean up file descriptors
        close(in);
        close(out);

        // Wait for kill signal and exit
        while (waitpid(sshpid, NULL, 0) == -1)
                if (errno != EINTR)
                        fatal("Couldn't wait for ssh process: %s",
                            strerror(errno));

        //exit(err == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        exit(0);
 }
```